# Node.js async loop with callback from function before next loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I have an `async.whilst` loop, which is for-looping through a string array called `hashtag`on each cycle.

During the for-loop, `searchTwitter()` function is fired. I need the for-loop to pause until a callback is returned from the `searchTwitter()` function, then there's a 2 second pause, then the for-loop continues to the next string in the `hashtag` array to pass to `searchTwitter()`.

After for loop finishes, there's a timeout in the async.whilst loop, for 10 seconds and then whilst loop reloads the for-loop cycle again.

My code below is firing all the `searchTwitter()` functions immediately without waiting for callback or `setTimeout(callback,2000)` :

```
async.whilst(
    function () { return 0 == 0 },
    function (callback) {

        for (var i = 0; i < hashtag.length; i++) {
            searchTwitter(hashtag[i]);
            setTimeout(callback, 2000);
        }

        setTimeout(callback, 10000);
    },
    function (err) {
    }
);


function searchTwitter(tag, callback){

    T.get('search/tweets', { q: '#fun', count: 100 }, function(err, data, response) {
        console.log(data);
        callback();
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Anatoliy mentioned in his answer, `async.eachSeries` is going to help you out with that for loop. It will loop over your `hashtag` array, calling the next item only after you've called the `callback` function.

The trick to getting those delays in place is to call your `setTimeout` functions inside the callbacks from `searchTwitter` and the completion callback from `eachSeries`. Like so:

```
async.whilst(
    function () { return true }, // true makes more sense than 0 == 0, especially from a readability standpoint
    function (callback) {
        async.eachSeries(hashtag, function(tag, callback) {
            searchTwitter(tag, function() {
                setTimeout(callback, 2000); // Wait 2 seconds before going on to the next tag
            })
        }, function(err) {
            setTimeout(callback, 10000); // Wait 10 seconds before looping over the hashtags again
        });
    },
    function (err) {
    }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
async.whilst(
    function () { return 0 == 0 },
    function (callback) {
        async.eachSeries(hashtag, searchTwitter, callback);
    },
    function (err) {
    }
);

function searchTwitter(tag, done) {
    // search for `tag`
    // call `done` when done
}
```

Read docs: [async#eachSeries](https://github.com/caolan/async#eachseriesarr-iterator-callback)